# Ionic/Angular Cookie issue on iOS

Tags: ios, angular, cookies, ionic-framework

I am using .Net core for backend, and authenticating users using cookies. My ionic application is working perfectly fine on android, where cookies are returned on login and are set automatically and being used for every request. 
Trying it out on iOS, the cookies work fine as long as the app has not been closed (meaning both cookies sent from the server are being returned with every request).
If the app is closed and then restarted, I notice only one cookie being sent with the requests. This behavior is very weird since one cookie is being saved and is persistent throughout app restarts, in opposition to the other cookie that is no longer available after the restart. Does anyone have the slightest idea of what might be causing this? 
Again, the same code was used for both platforms, and no manual handling for the cookies is being done.

Comment: I have discovered that the main reason for this is the way iOS browser behaves. The returned cookie that is disappearing has the tag "Session" as expiry (When viewed in developer console). That's why it is cleared whenever the browser is closed: i.e the app is closed. Therefore it seems that iOS WebView will clear any cookie that does not have an expiry date. The question remains on how to change this to provide a working scenario , and preferably from the backend side.